# Multi-objective optimisation methods

Tags: reference-request, optimization

I have recently encountered a few problems concerning the optimisation (maximization or minimization) of one or more functions under some constraints. Are there any good introductory tutorials or books about this kind of optimisation problem? I want to learn more about it.

Thanks.

Comment: Convex Optimization by Boyd and Vandenberghe is a great textbook that's [free online](http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/).

Comment: @littleO, thanks. BTW, why *Convex*? What about concave?

Comment: If we want to maximize a concave function $g$, it's equivalent to minimizing the convex function $f = -g$.  So we only need to discuss how to minimize convex functions.  (Of course we often want to minimize non-convex functions as well, but Boyd and Vandenberghe focus on convex optimization where many special techniques and theory are available.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Convex Optimization", as noted in the comment by littleO is indeed a great reference.  A convex optimization problem involves minimizing a convex objective function over a convex set.  If the function is concave, no problem, just maximize instead.  The convexity of the feasible set ensures that a local optimimum is indeed a global optimum.  Convex optimization covers some important well-studied classes of problems such as linear programming (which involves a linear objective function and a linear constraints), quadratic programming (quadratic objective function, linear constraints), semi-definite programming, etc.

If you are dealing with problems with discrete (integer) variables, which is the case for many real world problems then you do not have a convex optimization problem, and the problem is much harder.  Then I would refer you to Optimization Over Integers by Bertsimas and Weismantel ([here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0975914626)).  I would also recommend the ongoing Discrete Optimization online course at Coursera ([here](https://www.coursera.org/course/optimization)).

Comment: Thank you so much for these reference.